# How To Draw Square on Canvas With Button

Tags: html, button, draw

I know how to draw a square, but how could I make it so that it only draws when I click on a "Draw Square" button? Also, I know to make a button (`<p><button onclick="rect();">Rectangle</button></p>`), but how do you link it to the javascript? Any help at all would be much appreciated...

HTML5:

---

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

---

JAVASCRIPT:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    rect = {},
    drag = false;


    function init() {
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}


function mouseDown(e) {
  rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  drag = true;
}


function mouseUp() {
  drag = false;
}


function mouseMove(e) {
  if (drag) {
    rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
    rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY ;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    draw();
  }
}


function draw() {
  ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
}


init();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have actually already linked your button to a javascript function by specifying its 'onclick' attribute.

Now you just need to add a `rect()` function to your js that will draw a rectangle.

Comment: Please... can you show me how to do that:)? Do I just add.........   function rect()
{ **code above** }    That's what I did and it's still not working:(

Comment: Nice it works! I made the rect() function like you said and now I can draw a rectangle at the click of the button:) Unfortunately though, there's still a problem. Every time I click on the canvas to make a new rectangle (or to just do something else), the old rectangle disappears. It also didn't work when at all I tried to use it on my iPod... why?